# Vue component script indent rules conflicting

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, eslint, lint

I'm trying to set some ESLint rules to my new Vue project extending both *eslint-plugin-vue* and *airbnb*. I could set up everything just fine, except for the  tag inside Vue components.

The accepted default would be like:

```
<script>
export default {
    name: 'Login',
};
</script>
```

However I'm trying to get this code style to be accepted:

```
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'Login',
    };
</script>
```

Using the rule *vue/script-indent* ( https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/script-indent.html ) I could get the job done with the *baseIndent* set to 1. However, the lint rule is still complaining about it.

I tried placing this in this *.eslintrc.json* file:

```
"overrides": [
    {
        "files": [",*.vue"],
        "rules": {
            "indent": "off"
        }
    }
]
```

Also tried using the *ignoredNodes* from indent rules ( https://eslint.org/docs/rules/indent ) however I think I couldn't get my AST selectors right.

This is my current *.eslintrc.json* file:

```
{
    "extends": [
        "plugin:vue/recommended",
        "@vue/airbnb"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "indent": [2, 4],
        "vue/html-indent": [2, 4],
        "vue/script-indent": [2, 4, {
            "baseIndent": 1
        }],

        "vue/singleline-html-element-content-newline": 0,

        "vue/eqeqeq": 2
    },
    "plugins": [
        "html"
    ]
}
```

I get these errors when running lint:

```
   8:1  error  Expected indentation of 0 spaces but found 4  indent
   9:1  error  Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 8  indent
  10:1  error  Expected indentation of 0 spaces but found 4  indent
```

Comment: Hey, I've had the same problem rn, but overriding the `indent` rule for `*.vue` files helped. In your example you have `"files": [",*.vue"]` instead of `"files": ["*.vue"]`, maybe that was the problem

Answer (score -3):

If you're using VSCode, this setting will probably help you out:

```
// settings.json
{
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint"
  // ...
}
```

At the time I saved the file before this setting, it linted with rules that wasn't defined by me even though I've written them on .eslintrc.js.

This setting made it work just fine.

But also check out the conflicts between eslint-plugin-html and eslint-plugin-vue.